# UI difference between XAML and C# code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have built a UI block in XAML that will represent a customizable web page test automation. No problem so far.
I'm now trying to translate these UI elements from XAML to the C# code behind, so I can generate the UI blocks dynamically, and there are differences I can't explain: several element are not displayed when generated from the code behind.

Screenshot for comparison:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVezM.jpg]

XAML code:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="TestPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <Grid Margin="0,20,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,0,0,0">Page link here</CheckBox>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,10,0">Status here</TextBlock>
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="30,8,0,0">Url to check:</CheckBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,5,5,0">Url here</TextBox>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0">Status here</TextBlock>
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="30,8,0,0">Text to check:</CheckBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,5,5,0">Text here</TextBox>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0">Status here</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

C# code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{        
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new Test(this);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public MainWindow Window { get; set; }

    public Grid Grid { get; set; }

    public CheckBox PageCB { get; set; }
    public TextBlock PageStatus { get; set; }

    public CheckBox UrlCB { get; set; }
    public TextBox UrlTB { get; set; }
    public TextBlock UrlStatus { get; set; }

    public CheckBox TextCB { get; set; }
    public TextBox TextTB { get; set; }
    public TextBlock TextStatus { get; set; }

    public Test(MainWindow window)
    {
        this.Window = window;

        this.Grid = new Grid();
        this.Grid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);

        // Columns
        this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

        ColumnDefinition col = new ColumnDefinition();
        col.Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Star);
        this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);

        this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

        // Rows
        this.Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        this.Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        this.Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

        // Elements
        this.PageCB = new CheckBox();
        this.PageCB.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0);
        this.PageCB.Content = "Page link here";
        Grid.SetColumn(this.PageCB, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(this.PageCB, 0);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(this.PageCB, 2);
        this.Grid.Children.Add(this.PageCB);

        this.PageStatus = new TextBlock();
        this.PageStatus.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 10, 0);
        this.PageStatus.Text = "Status here";
        Grid.SetColumn(this.PageStatus, 2);
        Grid.SetRow(this.PageStatus, 0);
        this.Grid.Children.Add(this.PageStatus);

        this.UrlCB = new CheckBox();
        this.UrlCB.Margin = new Thickness(30, 8, 0, 0);
        this.UrlCB.Content = "Url to check:";
        Grid.SetColumn(this.UrlCB, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(this.UrlCB, 1);
        this.Grid.Children.Add(this.UrlCB);

        this.UrlTB = new TextBox();
        this.UrlTB.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 0);
        this.UrlTB.Text = "Url here";
        Grid.SetColumn(this.UrlTB, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(this.UrlTB, 1);
        this.Grid.Children.Add(this.UrlTB);

        this.UrlStatus = new TextBlock();
        this.UrlStatus.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 10, 0);
        this.UrlStatus.Text = "Status here";
        Grid.SetColumn(this.UrlStatus, 2);
        Grid.SetRow(this.UrlStatus, 1);
        this.Grid.Children.Add(this.UrlStatus);

        this.TextCB = new CheckBox();
        this.TextCB.Margin = new Thickness(30, 8, 0, 0);
        this.TextCB.Content = "Text to check:";
        Grid.SetColumn(this.TextCB, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(this.TextCB, 2);
        this.Grid.Children.Add(this.TextCB);

        this.TextTB = new TextBox();
        this.TextTB.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 0);
        this.TextTB.Text = "Text here";
        Grid.SetColumn(this.TextTB, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(this.TextTB, 2);
        this.Grid.Children.Add(this.TextTB);

        this.TextStatus = new TextBlock();
        this.TextStatus.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 10, 0);
        this.TextStatus.Text = "Status here";
        Grid.SetColumn(this.TextStatus, 2);
        Grid.SetRow(this.TextStatus, 2);
        this.Grid.Children.Add(this.TextStatus);

        this.Window.TestPanel.Children.Add(this.Grid);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Yeah I noticed it, that's why XAML is so great! But I need to generate this block like 19 times, so the code behind will win in the end.

Comment: Why not put the block in a `UserControl` and simply add the `UserControl` in the code-behind? You'd have the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I second the suggestion that you should create a User Control and reuse that. However, to answer the question directly, you need to set the Column and Row `Width` and `Height` properties to `Auto`.

```
// Columns
this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });

ColumnDefinition col = new ColumnDefinition();
col.Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Star);
this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);

this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });

// Rows
this.Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
this.Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
this.Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'm still a WPF beginner and didn't know about User Controls, I'll dig that way.

Comment: Solution is fine, but this is still bad practice ;)

Comment: @user853710 - Which is why I suggested the User Control method :) But the answer might be useful for someone else who comes across this looking to simply create one column, for example, so tried get best of both worlds.

Comment: [Easy UserControl tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/user-control-in-wpf/)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you arent setting the height or the rows and width of the columns inside your layout grid. The default height/width isnt auto but * size.

So this code:

```
        // Columns
    this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

    ColumnDefinition col = new ColumnDefinition();
    col.Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Star);
    this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);

    this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

    // Rows
    this.Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
    this.Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
    this.Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
```

Should be :

```
// Columns
this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Star) });
this.Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });

// Rows
this.Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
this.Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
this.Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
```